# Indexed Property Error: Must be Qualified and Arguments Explicitly Supplied

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

While running the code I've included below I receive the error

> "EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code.

I'm then told to look at the inner exception for details...and there I see under Data:

> "In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user."

And under Inner Exception --> Message:

> "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.)"

The code Visual Studio thinks is at fault is:

```
Dim qpeople = (From p In dbContext2.PEOPLE _
                                    Where p.PEOPLE_ID = ID _
                                    Order By p.CREATE_DATE Descending _
                                    Select p).FirstOrDefault
```

The larger code context is:

```
 Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim semester As String = ddlwhSemester.SelectedValue
    Dim year As String = txtwhYear.Text
    Dim exists As String = "N"
    Dim pcsemester As String = ddlSemester.SelectedItem.Text
    Dim pcyear As String = ddlYear.SelectedItem.Text
    Using dbContext As pbu_housingEntities = New pbu_housingEntities
        ' Get the list of residents in webHousing.
        Dim qresidents = (From p In dbContext.Residents _
                          Where p.semester = semester _
                          Where p.year = year _
                         Select p.people_code_id)
        Using dbContext2 As Campus6Entities = New Campus6Entities
            ' Get the list of students in PowerCampus.
            Dim qstudents = (From p In dbContext2.RESIDENCies _
                             Join a In dbContext2.ACADEMICs _
                             On a.PEOPLE_CODE_ID Equals p.PEOPLE_CODE_ID _
                             Where p.ACADEMIC_TERM = pcsemester _
                             Where p.ACADEMIC_YEAR = pcyear _
                             Where a.ACADEMIC_TERM = pcsemester _
                             Where a.ACADEMIC_YEAR = pcyear _
                             Where a.PROGRAM = "UND" _
                             Where (a.CLASS_LEVEL = "FR" _
                             Or a.CLASS_LEVEL = "FRNR" _
                             Or a.CLASS_LEVEL = "FRST" _
                             Or a.CLASS_LEVEL = "SO" _
                             Or a.CLASS_LEVEL = "JR" _
                             Or a.CLASS_LEVEL = "SR" _
                             Or a.CLASS_LEVEL = "SR5" _
                             Or a.CLASS_LEVEL = "Tran") _
                             Select p.PEOPLE_ID).Distinct
            For Each row In qstudents
                exists = "N"
                For Each res In qresidents
                    If row.ToString = res.ToString Then
                        exists = "Y"
                    End If
                Next
                If exists = "Y" Then
                    ' Skip adding.
                Else
                    ' Add a row.
                    ' Get the ID
                    Dim ID As String = row
                    ' Get info from PowerCampus
                    Dim qpeople = (From p In dbContext2.PEOPLE _
                                    Where p.PEOPLE_ID = ID _
                                    Order By p.CREATE_DATE Descending _
                                    Select p).FirstOrDefault
                    Dim people_code_id As String = qpeople.PEOPLE_CODE_ID
                    Dim qacademic = (From p In dbContext2.ACADEMICs _
                                     Where p.PEOPLE_CODE_ID = people_code_id _
                                     Where p.ACADEMIC_TERM = pcsemester _
                                     Where p.ACADEMIC_YEAR = pcyear _
                                     Order By p.CREATE_DATE Descending _
                                     Select p.CLASS_LEVEL).FirstOrDefault
                    Dim qaddress = (From p In dbContext2.ADDRESSes _
                                    Where p.PEOPLE_ORG_CODE_ID = people_code_id _
                                    Where p.ADDRESS_TYPE = "Perm" _
                                    Order By p.CREATE_DATE Descending _
                                    Select p).FirstOrDefault
                    Dim qdemographics = (From p In dbContext2.DEMOGRAPHICS _
                                         Where p.PEOPLE_CODE_ID = people_code_id _
                                         Order By p.CREATE_DATE Descending _
                                         Select p.GENDER).FirstOrDefault

                    ' Create the new occupant.
                    Dim newres As New Resident
                    newres.people_code_id = ID
                    newres.person_name = qpeople.FIRST_NAME + " " + qpeople.MIDDLE_NAME + " " + qpeople.LAST_NAME
                    newres.first_name = qpeople.FIRST_NAME
                    newres.last_name = qpeople.LAST_NAME
                    newres.class_level = qacademic
                    newres.gender = qdemographics
                    newres.semester = semester
                    newres.year = year
                    newres.email = qaddress.EMAIL_ADDRESS
                    newres.create_date = Date.Now
                    dbContext.Residents.AddObject(newres)
                    dbContext.SaveChanges()
                End If
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice this before but you are setting your ID like this:

```
Dim ID As String = row
```

Try converting the ID to a Int before the linq query.

Comment: Geez, I'd tried everything and its mother to make this thing work (totally rewriting the above code) and the fix was that simple.

Comment: Well, that worked...unfortunately, I realized afterwards that the reason I had it set to string was b/c integer cuts off the leading zeroes - and, unfortunately, the other database uses leading zeroes.

Comment: Using PEOPLE_CODE_ID everywhere solves the leading zeros issue, as it always starts with the letter P.

Answer (score 2):

Check your db and make sure the primary key is there.  I had a similar issue and found that the primary key was not defined.  Just a thought, might not be the problem but worth a quick check.

Comment: Thanks for the thought...unfortunately it is already set as the primary key...so no luck on the easy fix. :-/